# How to calculate bytes needed for a gray scale video

Tags: pixels, grayscale

> What is the minimum memory (in bytes) for saving five seconds gray scale video with a frame rate of 14 fps in which the dimension of each frame is 480x320? Each  pixel in this video requires to be able to store at least 6 different statuses

Looking at similar questions on the board, I assumed the calculation would be 
something like this:

480*320*8 bit*14 fps*5 seconds = 8601600

8601600/8 = 10752000 bytes

The correct answer is: 4032000 but I don't get how that was calculated, nor what is meant by 6 statuses?

Comment: Is this a homework? 8 bit can store 256 states of a pixel, but you need only 6. Do you have fixed byte size? Can you do compression?...

Comment: What were those "similar questions"?

Comment: More like an exam set from last year i'm trying to understand. There is no compression no. The similar questions: http://superuser.com/questions/829056/how-to-calculate-bytes-need-for-an-image-with-256-level-gray-scale?newreg=2888100354bd478bb5a99f6883d959d1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559103/video-size-calculation - I only know what i've quoted, but I assume that the byte size is not fixed, no.

Comment: There are six different shades of gray. So you can't use 1 bit for color nor would it make sense to use 32 bits. Use the minimal amount of bits that would let you have and indicator for six different kinds of grey and do the calculation like you did.

Comment: @Seth the question is not clear, 3 bits can have 8 different states, so it's fine to store the 6 colours here. However e.g. 8 pixels can have a total number of 6^8 states, which can be stored on 21 bits (2^21>6^8) instead of 24. And there is still further space for optimization...

Comment: @Seth Thanks, that made it easier to understand.. why divide by 16 though? if 480x320x6 bit x14 fps x 5 seconds = 645152000 -> 645152000/16 = 4032000

Comment: It's pretty clear as it's asking about the `minimum memory` and as it is an artificial school book question (no compression etc.). So it's storing 14*5 data structures with a resolution of 470*320 pixels. The variable you're left with is the number of bits for color depth. The absolute minimum you would need would be the smallest 2^n that that is >= 6 which would be 2^3. if you do have information about the data structure you would have to adjust accordingly e.g. the smallest possible value for [bitmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage) would be 4.

Comment: My comment does contain the answer but you're division by 16 is wrong, even if it would net you the same result. You should check your learning materials on how decimal to binary conversion works. You need to find the minimal amount of bits you need to have six different states. In order to have some magic software assign a grey value to one of each of those states and display the video.

Comment: @Seth Mhh .. wait. So I have to convert my decimal to binary? so base 2 100110011101000011110100000000 length 30.. which is the least to 2^4 = 16 therefore 480*320*6*14*5 -> 645152000/2^4 = 4032000

Comment: I did add an answer which goes into more detail on what I did to arrive at the desired number (which should be what's usually required). You did convert the wrong number. I hope my answer is sufficient to clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so lets do this step by step. You already identified the most important information which is:

- Resolution of 480x320
- 14 frames per second
- 5 second recording time
- 6 different statuses

It's all just a simple multiplication of those numbers. The only catch is, is that you can't simply use the 6 for the number of statues but you need to do something with it. The text tells you that this 6 responds to every single pixel in a single frame for that recording. As such it's (most likely) the color depth. The color depth of a picture is usually given as the number of bits that is used to "encode" the color. It would be quite cumbersome to write down the names of the colors each pixel has (and would take a lot more space).

So what you need to do is convert that decimal number 6 to its binary equivalent. There are [various](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary) approaches on how to do it but the end result should always be the binary representation 110. With that information you know that the minimum amount of bits to represent the decimal number 6 in binary is 3.

If it was an IRL example you would have to account for data structures and definitions. So e.g. for a [bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage) it looks like you would need at least 4 bit. As your exercise doesn't specify any additional information, the person who came up with that question likely wants you to use 3 bits as the color depth.

Now that we have all the details it's just:

```
color depth * resolution * frames per second * seconds
3 bit * (480 pixels * 320 pixels) * 14 * 5 = 32 256 000 bit
32 256 000 bit / 8 bit = 4 032 000 bytes
```

What that exercise is doing is checking whenever you have an understanding of the technical terms and are able to convert decimal numbers to binary ones.

For fun you could assume you'd need 105 different kinds of gray. In that case you would end up with 9187 Kilobytes.